# Whennew() call in powermockito not working

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I'm using Mockito and PowerMockito to instantiate a mock when a constructor is called:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ConVibe.class)
public class ConVibeTests {

    ConVibe task;

    @Mock ShapeEffect shapeEffect;



    @Test
    public void verify_shape_effect() {

        whenNew(ShapeEffect.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(shapeEffect);
        task.call();

        // Omitted
    }

    // Omitted

}
```

This is the call to the constructor that I wanted to mock, located inside the function call() in the class conVibe:

```
final ShapeEffect effect = new ShapeEffect(mode, new RepService());
```

The fact is that the real constructor is called (where there is a DB call that obviously fail) instead of creating a mock.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong runner - if you want to use PowerMock, you need to use the `PowerMockRunner`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ConVibe.class)
public class ConVibeTests {
```